# How to link one docker container with another docker container

Tags: tomcat, docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile

I want to run server and UI in tomcat so i create two dockerfile one for server and another for UI. Then i run the server tomcat container, it run successfully after that i run the UI tomcat container.
I getting error

`connection refused error`

What do I need to do to have container interacting with each other?

Answer (score 0):

You should use *--link* option when you run a tomcat sesrver.

```
$ docker run -d -P --name tomcat-ui --link your_first_container_name:tomcat your_image our_command
```

This will link the new tomcat UI container with the container you created earlier. The --link flag takes the form:

```
--link <name or id>:alias
```